# Machine Learning Epochs and loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Input data = 11000 points with 10000 training and 1000 testing.

I am using Keras Sequential LSTM, I am training it with batch size 128 and epochs 1000.

I have noticed that over the first 100 the improvement of loss is very low and then over the next 100 the loss improves better than the first 100,
Then over the 300-400th epoch the loss improves quite well.

Is this normal? Or is my model overfitting?

Thank you

Comment: What defines overfitting is how your model performs on the test data. The loss curve can vary significantly with different architectures, learning rate, data quality, loss types and their combinations

Comment: What is your expectation about loss? what do you mean by improve? DO you mean decreased? if loss decrease it means the model is learning the data in train set; overfit is measured based on validation set loss or other metrics on val/dev sets.

Answer (score 0):

So you could imagine the loss with a sled ride down a hill. You start at the top and want to reach the bottom of the hill (the minima of your function). The closer you get to the bottom the lesser the loss. At first, the hill isn't that steep so you get to the bottom of the hill quite slow. As you go further down the hill becomes steeper and steeper and you become faster and faster until you reach the bottom of the hill.
So like in reality every hill is different in its height and steepness, so you can't say which speed (loss improvement) in which time (epoch) is normal.
As long as your loss is improving (getting smaller) everything is fine and your model is learning.
[image]

A good introduction to ML and gradient decent could be found [here](https://blog.paperspace.com/intro-to-optimization-in-deep-learning-gradient-descent/)

As for the question of overfitting. To check for overfitting you should have set aside a dataset specifically for testing your model. If your model performs well during training but poorly during testing it is likely that it is overfitted. At least if you prepared and split your data correctly.